# Detect the type of font that is displayed in an image

Tags: css, photoshop

Does anyone by any chance know what font this is?

http://spiketradinginc.com/images/font.png

I was thinking Helvetica possibly? Wasn't sure I'm not a designer.

What would be the best resume font that would look good on paper? (Print/Web)

Comment: This is not programming related and does not belong on StackOverflow.

Comment: I don't see the font anywhere on this page. Can you post a screenshot, or a link to the website where you found it?

Comment: Why did you delete the link to the font that was posted here before?

Comment: I'm pretty sure its in the font-section right?

Comment: @BlakeTallos The font-section of which application or website?

Comment: There are some tools that you can use to identify fonts in images. See here: http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2008/12/7-free-tools-to-identify-a-font/

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I appreciate the link. What's up with all the negetive feedback from stackoverflow members?

Comment: @BlakeTallos Mainly it's because this question is off-topic. This question appears to be unrelated to computer programming, but it might possibly be relevant on http://tex.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Don't take this personally, but it would be best to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) before posting questions.

Comment: @ Anderson Green Well, thanks I appreciate the link. I didn't even know that website existed.

Answer (score 2):

The first font in the image is **[Museo Slab 500](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/exljbris/museo-slab/500/)**.

Here's how I found that out:

1. Open the image with [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/)
2. *Layers > Rotate/Zoom*
3. Rotate by *-19.75°*
4. With the *Rectangle Select* tool, highlight just 1 font
5. *Image > Crop To Selection*

That gave me the following image:

[image]

I then uploaded that to [WhatTheFont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/), filled in the boxes for each character (it didn't successfully select the letter `i`, so I left them boxes blank).

The results showed 5 possible matches, and by carefully comparing each font sample to the original image, I deduced it was Museo Slab 500.

You can follow this process to find the other fonts in your image!